# Compatibility of TensorFlow Quantum on Windows

Tags: machine-learning

I created a Jupyter file around two years ago that relies on the following packages:

[image]

However, it seems that Google has discontinued support for TensorFlow Quantum on Windows. This poses a problem as my file contains an important project that I need to work on.

Is there any way to make the file compatible with Windows? I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Does it have continued support on any other OS? For instance windows now allows you to install an [ubuntu terminal](https://pureinfotech.com/install-ubuntu-windows-10/#install_ubuntu_windows10_gui) that you can run inside windows.